# Windows Authentication in Firebird 2.5

Tags: delphi, authentication, windows-authentication, firebird2.5, dbexpress

Can I login to firebird database using a Windows user instead of using SYSDBA and MASTERKEY credential? If Yes, please let me know the way to connect to the firebird database.

I am using Delphi XE3 and Firebird 2.5. I need to authenticate user by logged in user after updating config file for "trusted" in place of default "native" as specified here: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/2_5/rnfb25-fbconf-authent.html

This is my code :

```
SQLConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
//SQLConnection1.Params.add('user_name='); 
//SQLConnection1.Params.add('password='); 
SQLConnection1.Params.add('os authentication=True') ; 
SQLConnection1.Connected:= True
```

It still asks for credentials.

Comment: Which DB client are you using - FireDAC, UniDAC, Interbase, ADO, or...? It's crucial to get a specific answer.

Comment: I am using DbExpress. Need to access firebird database table data without providing user name & password. Just want to use Windows authentication to access table. Many thanks.

Comment: I used following code but asking for credentials:
    //SQLConnection1.Params.add('user_name=');
    //SQLConnection1.Params.add('password=');
      SQLConnection1.Params.add('os authentication=True') ; 
      SQLConnection1.Connected:= True;

Comment: Have you set to False the LoginPrompt property of SQLConnection1 ?.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Yes, I set LoginPrompt to false.

Comment: I've tried to update your post because it's obviously about the client side, not server (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16221614).

Comment: @VictoriaMarotoSilva Ok. So at client side, please let me know how to access the firebird using Windows authentication. Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried not including `user_name=` and `password=`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, that seems to happen (notice `//` comment chars). The edit is inaccurate. The rejected one from me copied them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I used double slash(//), means not included user_name= and password=

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question to show the actual code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I did. But it's been rejected https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16221614 :( I was trying to do the best with this question.

Comment: @VictoriaMarotoSilva I was addressing the OP, as he should have done that when initially asking the question. I will add them myself in a sec

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I know. I was trying to report you an incorrect review result ;) Thank you for this question update anyway.

Comment: @Victoria there is no way for me to revert the already made decision, and I suppose neither can Mark, but if you really want to bring it up, I think you can do it on META.stackexchange.net

Answer (score 2):

> (V.2.1) From Firebird 2.1 onward, Windows “Trusted User” security can
>   be applied for authenticating Firebird users on a Windows host. The
>   Trusted User's security context is passed to the Firebird server and,
>   if it succeeds, it is used to determine the Firebird security user
>   name.
>
> Simply omitting the user and password parameters from the DPB/SPB will
>   automatically cause Windows Trusted User authentication to be applied,
>   in almost all cases. See the Environment section, below, for
>   exceptions

from [official documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb210-wintrusted.html)

Also, take a look at this question -  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154735/how-to-enable-windows-authentication-in-firebird-2-5

Comment: I know how to use **ISC_USER & ISC_PASSWORD**:
C:\Pr~\bin>set ISC_USER=user1
C:\Pr~\bin>set ISC_PASSWORD=12345.
How to add new **isc_dpb_trusted_auth** parameter to the DPB? What syntax I need to use? Thanks.

Comment: @Vinod_cmdl read the dbExpress sources and find the function that creates DPB and check what string name it uses. Unified Interbase library uses "trusted_auth" name - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311652/976391

Answer (score 0):

If `User_Name` parameter of the `TSQLConnection` object is not set `(User_Name= )`, Windows Authentication connection mode is used.

Also set `Authentication = mixed` or trusted in `firebird.conf` file, **and restart FirebirdServer service**

If you don't set `user_name` and 'password' params in code (In your code have been commented), add them in design time. It's enough to add only `User_Name`.

If you want to use :

```
SQLConnection1.Params.add('user_name='); // this is enough
SQLConnection1.Params.add('password=');
```

remove `user_name` and `password` params from SQLConnection.Params in design time.

Note : **Do not use:**

```
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['User_Name'] := '';
```

This just removes parameter from list.

**Update**

[image]

This works for me. As you see in firebird.conf Autentication is trusted only.
SQLConnection params : user name and password are empty.
And SQLConnection is connected.

Try to repeat this picture.

A'm using Delphi 2010.

Comment: "Martin, I don't want to mess with you."  No worries.  Anyway, I've done what I should have done in the first place and tried my code with the server's authentication = trusted.  It fails to connect, giving the error message the OP quoted.  So I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @Val Marinov I tried but getting this message "Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login." Any help?

Comment: That would stop working if he sets username and password as Windows Environment Variables. I am not sure if DBX has the required constant for enforcing trusted auth. Unified Interbase does have, though - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311652/976391

Comment: Do I have to add the Windows user in security2.fdb database as well or somewhere else? I am getting "Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.." message.

Comment: @Vinod_cmdl No.

Comment: @Val Marinov Thanks. It worked for me.
My application is using DbGo component as well. So Could anyone please help me to know how to ADOConnection1 to connect using Windows Authentication. Thanks.